# The old file get remove from jQuery fileupload control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Suppose I am uploading one file from as shown in snippet code and then after again I am uploading the two files from same upload click control in that case the old file get loose from file upload control and newly uploaded file get display on hover of upload control

Steps to reproduce :

1) When I select one file on click of Select Attachment button the view looks as below image

[image]

2) Now again when I select two image on click of Select Attachment button the old image/file gets remove and the new files get display. please review below screenshot

[image]

3) On click of delete also the Old file name remain on Upload control(Can see on hover effect)

I had taken the code from [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1208892/Lightweight-Multiple-File-Upload-with-Thumbnail-Pr)

```js
//I added event handler for the file upload control to access the files properties.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

//To save an array of attachments 
var AttachmentArray = [];

//counter for attachment array
var arrCounter = 0;

//to make sure the error message for number of files will be shown only one time.
var filesCounterAlertStatus = false;

//un ordered list to keep attachments thumbnails
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.className = ("thumb-Images");
ul.id = "imgList";

function init() {
    //add javascript handlers for the file upload event
    document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

//the handler for file upload event
function handleFileSelect(e) {
    //to make sure the user select file/files
    if (!e.target.files) return;

    //To obtaine a File reference
    var files = e.target.files;

    // Loop through the FileList and then to render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        //instantiate a FileReader object to read its contents into memory
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information and apply validation.
        fileReader.onload = (function (readerEvt) {
            return function (e) {

                //Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
                ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt)

                //Render attachments thumbnails.
                RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt);

                //Fill the array of attachment
                FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt)
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        // readAsDataURL: The result property will contain the file/blob's data encoded as a data URL.
        // More info about Data URI scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

//To remove attachment once user click on x button
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('div').on('click', '.img-wrap .close', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');

        //to remove the deleted item from array
        var elementPos = AttachmentArray.map(function (x) { return x.FileName; }).indexOf(id);
        if (elementPos !== -1) {
            AttachmentArray.splice(elementPos, 1);
        }

        //to remove image tag
        $(this).parent().find('img').not().remove();

        //to remove div tag that contain the image
        $(this).parent().find('div').not().remove();

        //to remove div tag that contain caption name
        $(this).parent().parent().find('div').not().remove();

        //to remove li tag
        var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#imgList li');
        for (var i = 0; li = lis[i]; i++) {
            if (li.innerHTML == "") {
                li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
            }
        }

    });
}
)

//Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
function ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt)
{
    //To check file type according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFileType(readerEvt.type) == false) {
        alert("The file (" + readerEvt.name + ") does not match the upload conditions, You can only upload jpg/png/gif files");
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    //To check file Size according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFileSize(readerEvt.size) == false) {
        alert("The file (" + readerEvt.name + ") does not match the upload conditions, The maximum file size for uploads should not exceed 300 KB");
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    //To check files count according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) == false) {
        if (!filesCounterAlertStatus) {
            filesCounterAlertStatus = true;
            alert("You have added more than 10 files. According to upload conditions you can upload 10 files maximum");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}

//To check file type according to upload conditions
function CheckFileType(fileType) {
    if (fileType == "image/jpeg") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (fileType == "image/png") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (fileType == "image/gif") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//To check file Size according to upload conditions
function CheckFileSize(fileSize) {
    if (fileSize < 300000) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//To check files count according to upload conditions
function CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) {
    //Since AttachmentArray.length return the next available index in the array, 
    //I have used the loop to get the real length
    var len = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < AttachmentArray.length; i++) {
        if (AttachmentArray[i] !== undefined) {
            len++;
        }
    }
    //To check the length does not exceed 10 files maximum
    if (len > 9) {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//Render attachments thumbnails.
function RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt)
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = ['<div class="img-wrap"> <span class="close">&times;</span>' +
        '<img class="thumb" style="display:none;" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(readerEvt.name), '" data-id="',
        readerEvt.name, '"/>' + '</div>'].join('');

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "FileNameCaptionStyle";
    li.appendChild(div);
    div.innerHTML = [readerEvt.name].join('');
    document.getElementById('Filelist').insertBefore(ul, null);
}

//Fill the array of attachment
function FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt)
{
    AttachmentArray[arrCounter] =
    {
        AttachmentType: 1,
        ObjectType: 1,
        FileName: readerEvt.name,
        FileDescription: "Attachment",
        NoteText: "",
        MimeType: readerEvt.type,
        Content: e.target.result.split("base64,")[1],
        FileSizeInBytes: readerEvt.size,
    };
    arrCounter = arrCounter + 1;
}
```

```css
/*Copied from bootstrap to handle input file multiple*/

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/*Also */

.btn-success {
  border: 1px solid #c5dbec;
  background: #D0E5F5;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2e6e9e;
}

/* This is copied from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/css/jquery.fileupload.css */

.fileinput-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fileinput-button input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: 'alpha(opacity=0)';
  font-size: 200px;
  direction: ltr;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul.thumb-Images li {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 120px;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-wrap .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #D0E5F5;
  padding: 5px 2px 2px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-wrap:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.FileNameCaptionStyle {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
  <span>Select Attachment</span>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
</span>
<output id="Filelist"></output>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question, you want manipulate the [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) [property of `<input>` elements with `type="file"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

> A FileList object that lists every selected file. This list has no
>   more than one member unless the multiple attribute is specified.

So, it returns so when even you perform the event on `<input type="file"/>` it returns only selected elements.
You can get the selected files. To get the selected files

In jQuery

```
$("#files")[0].files
```

[image]

And in pure js

```
document.getElementById('files').files;
```

[image]

It returns the array of selected elements. ***These are the items that are being shown on your upload file buttons.***

**So you can do a kind of hack things** For example you can set your own `title` attribute on the `<input type="file">` element. Browser does not allow to change the `FileList` so you need to use trick. Here is an sample snippet.

```
var title = "";
$("#imgList>li").each(function(){
    title += `${$(this).find(".FileNameCaptionStyle").text()}\n`;
});
$("#files").attr("title", title);
```

```js
//I added event handler for the file upload control to access the files properties.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

//To save an array of attachments 
var AttachmentArray = [];

//counter for attachment array
var arrCounter = 0;

//to make sure the error message for number of files will be shown only one time.
var filesCounterAlertStatus = false;

//un ordered list to keep attachments thumbnails
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.className = ("thumb-Images");
ul.id = "imgList";

function init() {
    //add javascript handlers for the file upload event
    document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

//the handler for file upload event
function handleFileSelect(e) {
    //to make sure the user select file/files
    if (!e.target.files) return;

    //To obtaine a File reference
    var files = e.target.files;

    // Loop through the FileList and then to render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        //instantiate a FileReader object to read its contents into memory
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information and apply validation.
        fileReader.onload = (function(readerEvt) {
            return function(e) {

                //Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
                ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt)

                //Render attachments thumbnails.
                RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt);

                //Fill the array of attachment
                FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt)
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        // readAsDataURL: The result property will contain the file/blob's data encoded as a data URL.
        // More info about Data URI scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

//To remove attachment once user click on x button
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#Filelist').on('click', '.img-wrap .close', function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
        //to remove the deleted item from array
        var elementPos = AttachmentArray.map(function(x) {
            return x.FileName;
        }).indexOf(id);
        if (elementPos !== -1) {
            AttachmentArray.splice(elementPos, 1);
        }

        //to remove image tag
        $(this).parent().find('img').not().remove();

        //to remove div tag that contain the image
        $(this).parent().find('div').not().remove();

        //to remove div tag that contain caption name
        $(this).parent().parent().find('div').not().remove();

        //to remove li tag
        var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#imgList li');
        for (var i = 0; li = lis[i]; i++) {
            if (li.innerHTML == "") {
                li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
            }
        }
        changeTitle();
    });
});

//Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
function ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt) {
    //To check file type according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFileType(readerEvt.type) == false) {
        alert("The file (" + readerEvt.name + ") does not match the upload conditions, You can only upload jpg/png/gif files");
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    //To check file Size according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFileSize(readerEvt.size) == false) {
        alert("The file (" + readerEvt.name + ") does not match the upload conditions, The maximum file size for uploads should not exceed 300 KB");
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    //To check files count according to upload conditions
    if (CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) == false) {
        if (!filesCounterAlertStatus) {
            filesCounterAlertStatus = true;
            alert("You have added more than 10 files. According to upload conditions you can upload 10 files maximum");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}

//To check file type according to upload conditions
function CheckFileType(fileType) {
    if (fileType == "image/jpeg") {
        return true;
    } else if (fileType == "image/png") {
        return true;
    } else if (fileType == "image/gif") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//To check file Size according to upload conditions
function CheckFileSize(fileSize) {
    if (fileSize < 300000) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//To check files count according to upload conditions
function CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) {
    //Since AttachmentArray.length return the next available index in the array, 
    //I have used the loop to get the real length
    var len = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < AttachmentArray.length; i++) {
        if (AttachmentArray[i] !== undefined) {
            len++;
        }
    }
    //To check the length does not exceed 10 files maximum
    if (len > 9) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Render attachments thumbnails.
function RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = ['<div class="img-wrap"> <span class="close">&times;</span>' +
        '<img class="thumb" style="display:none;" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(readerEvt.name), '" data-id="',
        readerEvt.name, '"/>' + '</div>'
    ].join('');

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "FileNameCaptionStyle";
    li.appendChild(div);
    div.innerHTML = [readerEvt.name].join('');
    document.getElementById('Filelist').insertBefore(ul, null);
    changeTitle();
}

//Fill the array of attachment
function FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt) {
    AttachmentArray[arrCounter] = {
        AttachmentType: 1,
        ObjectType: 1,
        FileName: readerEvt.name,
        FileDescription: "Attachment",
        NoteText: "",
        MimeType: readerEvt.type,
        Content: e.target.result.split("base64,")[1],
        FileSizeInBytes: readerEvt.size,
    };
    arrCounter = arrCounter + 1;
}

function changeTitle() {
    var title = "";
    $("#imgList>li").each(function() {
        title += `${$(this).find(".FileNameCaptionStyle").text()}\n`;
    });
    $("#files").attr("title", title);
}
```

```css
/*Copied from bootstrap to handle input file multiple*/
.btn {
    display: inline - block;
    padding: 6 px 12 px;
    margin - bottom: 0;
    font - size: 14 px;
    font - weight: normal;
    line - height: 1.42857143;
    text - align: center;
    white - space: nowrap;
    vertical - align: middle;
    cursor: pointer; -
    webkit - user - select: none; -
    moz - user - select: none; -
    ms - user - select: none;
    user - select: none;
    background - image: none;
    border: 1 px solid transparent;
    border - radius: 4 px;
}

/*Also */

.btn - success {
    border: 1 px solid# c5dbec;
    background: #D0E5F5;
    font - weight: bold;
    color: #2e6e9e;
}

/* This is copied from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/css/jquery.fileupload.css */

.fileinput-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fileinput-button input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: 'alpha(opacity= 0)
';
font - size: 200 px;
direction: ltr;
cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
    height: 80 px;
    width: 100 px;
    border: 1 px solid #000;
}

ul.thumb-Images li {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 120px;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-wrap .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: # D0E5F5;
    padding: 5 px 2 px 2 px;
    color: #000;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-wrap:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: # ff0000;
}

.FileNameCaptionStyle {
    font - size: 12 px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <span>Select Attachment</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
</span>
<output id="Filelist"></output>
```

Comment: Hi @Kiran Shahi, just now tried your code. It's not working properly. Assume I choose 3 images there, then I remove 1 image. Then after I submit, that 3 images uploaded. As We know it should be 2 image. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is simply html file input behavior. It has nothing to do with jQuery. File inputs will update their `value` and `files` property on every interaction. That means that if you:

1. click the input
2. select 5 files
3. click the input again
4. click "cancel" in the dialog (or hit the **esc** key)

Your file input will have an empty `value` and an empty `FileList` for its `files` property, because you made an empty selection with your last interaction.

If you want to keep a running list of all files selected and allow users to delete and add to it, you have to treat the file field as one-off input only rather than as a source of truth. You listen for changes to the input, take the incoming `files` data and add it to a local files array, **then you have to make sure to reset the input after each selection**.

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjn945vxnv) with a working example showing what I mean.

In this situation you won't be reading from the file input when you go to save your form data. You'll ignore the file input and manually add your files from your local variable.

Another thing to note is that the `files` property of a file input is read only. If you want to clear it out you can just set the `value` to `null` and that will take care of it.

Comment: how should i get the selected images in HttpPostedFileBase , as I am storing all the images using HttpPostedFileBase file, are you sure that all image I will get in file i.e. on controller side on submit click

Comment: The files are unchanged—they are still `File` objects from the file input. But you won't get them just by submitting the form, since they are not in the input. You're controlling these yourself so you have to manually add the image files to your form data before sending to the server. The codesandbox has an example showing how to get the files from the `FileUploader`. You just need to keep a reference to the object and call its `getFiles` method, which will give you the array of `File` objects.

Comment: I don't know how will I store image with your given code via HttpPostedFileBase file.

Comment: Okay, but that's not part of this question at all. That's also a server side concern. From the browser all you need to do is send the images along with your other form content as `FormData`. There are lots of resources for that (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object), but that's definitely out of scope on this question.